# Programmatically change the src of an img and adding li item in list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

How to change home **img src**, **href** and **anchor text** and in **list of HTML** and how to **Add item in list** using javaScript

```js
javascript: (function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('home')[0].src = 'imagelink.png';
})();
javascript: (function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('home')[0].href = 'http://www.cnn.com/';
})();
javascript: (function() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('home')[0].innerHTML = 'Main';
})();
```

```html
<ul class="m_menu_ul box_sizing">
  <li class="home">
    <img src="ld_menu_icon_qa_teal.png">
    <a href="homepage.html">Home</a>
  </li>
 <! -- adding this item as well -->
  <li class="qa">
    <img src="ld_menu_icon_qa_teal.png">
    <a href="quiz.html">Ask the Editor</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**I want to like this**

[image]

Comment: `javascript:` <-- why?? And why are you using three functions and referencing the same element li three times? You are not referencing the elements inside that actually have the data you want to change.

Comment: @epascarello change build website in the mobile app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### the `document.getElementsByClassName('home')` is not a list because you have just a single element with that class name

to make it work you have to select the correct elements:

```
document.querySelector('.home img').src = 'imagelink.png';
document.querySelector('.home a').href = 'http://www.cnn.com/';
document.querySelector('.home a').innerHTML = 'Main';
```

To add an item to the list :

```
const node = document.createElement('li');
node.appendChild(document.createTextNode('core vocabulary'));
 
document.querySelector('.m_menu_ul').appendChild(node);
```

Comment: it's working but how to add an item in this list, please

Comment: @Attaullah I changed the answer.

Comment: not working I tried.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, that you change the element with the class `home` which is a `<li>`. Use query selector and select the correct child elements (`img` and `a`):

```js
javascript: (function() {
  document.querySelector('.home img').src = 'imagelink.png';
})();
javascript: (function() {
  document.querySelector('.home a').href = 'http://www.cnn.com/';
})();
javascript: (function() {
  document.querySelector('.home a').innerHTML = 'Main';
})();
```

```html
<ul class="m_menu_ul box_sizing">
  <li class="home">
    <img src="ld_menu_icon_qa_teal.png">
    <a href="homepage.html">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="qa">
    <img src="ld_menu_icon_qa_teal.png">
    <a href="quiz.html">Ask the Editor</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it's working but how to add an item in this list, please